# Filter by price shows but doesn't filter

Tags: magento-1.9, price, layered-navigation, filter

My filter by price navigation shows but when a filter is clicked it just posts back to the same page with no change applied.

The filter categories are distributed evenly in line with the price set for products in the category and the correct number of products in each price range displays properly.

Comment: there may be problem with your product collection and filtering.

Comment: Do you mean something is misconfigured or data corrupt/similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with a template used on another store view.

We had the support team for the theme fixing another issue and layered navigation randomly appeared on multiple stores.

Answer (score 2):

In the admin panel go to **Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes.**

Find the attribute with code 'price'. Select the row.

Then **go to Properties->Front end properties.**

There is a drop down "`Use In Layered Navigation`" and another one "`Use In Search Results Layered Navigation`". Adjust these two as you like.

Comment: I have done that. The navigation shows OK and can be disabled using this method, but does not function properly when a filter price is selected.

Comment: i have use it display in price filter in website